# Serialize C# objects of unknown type to bytes using generics

Tags: c#, generics, serialization

**Usage example**

```
var qm = new QueueMessage("foo", 99);
var ba = ByteArraySerializer<QueueMessage>.Serialize(qm));
```

**Class that performs the serialization / deserialization**

```
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace Codingoutloud
{
   public static class ByteArraySerializer<T>
   {
      public static byte[] Serialize(T m)
      {
         var ms = new MemoryStream();
         try
         {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(ms, m);
            return ms.ToArray();
         }
         finally
         {
            ms.Close();
         }
      }

      public static T Deserialize(byte[] byteArray)
      {
         var ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
         try
         {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            return (T)formatter.Deserialize(ms);
         }
         finally
         {
            ms.Close();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Example of an object we would serialize**

```
using System;

namespace Codingoutloud
{
   [Serializable]
   public class QueueMessage
   {
      public QueueMessage() {}
      public QueueMessage(string name, int id)
      {
         Name = name;
         Id = id;
      }

      public string Name { get;  set; }
      public int Id { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that this only (de)serializes serializable objects, so it won't necessarily work for any _arbitrary_ unknown object.

Comment: Good point Jeff! Will work for unknown types as long as they are serializable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your methodology is solid on the generics front. Highly recommend using `using` statements rather than `try..finally`s. I also converted the methods to extension methods.

```
namespace Codingoutloud
{
   using System.IO;
   using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

   public static class ByteArraySerializer
   {
      public static byte[] Serialize<T>(this T m)
      {
         using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
         {
            new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(ms, m);
            return ms.ToArray();
         }
      }

      public static T Deserialize<T>(this byte[] byteArray)
      {
         using (var ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
         {
            return (T)new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(ms);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Great edits @Jesse C. Slicer - thanks - esp the asymmetric types on the extension methods.

Answer (score 2):

You should make sure that the object is Serializable.

A type that is serializable will return `true` for:

```
m.GetType().IsSerializable
```

Comment: thank you - good comment. I think that could be enforced with a Diagnostics.Debug.Assert or a CodeContract (from .NET 4).

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to serialize "unserializable" types via reflection, including private unserialized members and properties, though its a pain to deal with arbitrary type, you can certainly deal with all the common types easily, and provide for delegates to serialize/deserialize custom types.
The main thing for dealing with "unknown" types is to find out if they support a Set method - if not, you can't deserialize them, so no point to serialize them.